# Cadastrar com modal e javascript

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Tenho um form e dentro dele tenho vários modais com form dentro da modal como faço para salvar o que ta na modal sem interferir no form de fora pois com as modais que tem os forms dentro o form com a action processa/proc_cad_pessoa nao vai para  a página

```
<form role="form" method = "POST" action = "processa/proc_cad_pessoa.php" name="formulario">
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                                            <div class="step33">
                                                <h5><strong>Indentificação Pessoal</strong></h5>

                                                <hr>

                                                <div class="row mar_ned">

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="form-group  col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                                        <label>Nome</label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomepessoa" placeholder="Nome da Pessoa"/>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                                                        <label style="padding-top: 2em;">Sexo:</label>

                                                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="M">Masculino
                                                        </label>

                                                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="F">Feminino
                                                        </label><br/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div> <br/>
```

×
                                                                                
                                                                                Adicionar Ensino
                                                                            

                                                                            
                                                                                
                                                                                    
                                                                                        
                                                                                            Ensino: *
                                                                                            
                                                                                               
                                                                                            
                                                                                        
                                                                                    


                                                                                    

                                                                                        Cadastrar

Answer (score 0):

Não encontrei a tag `</form>` ser fechada . Seja mais específico na sua pergunta , está um pouco confusa porque não conhecemos seu cenário .

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você tem que deixar mais claro a diferença entre a tag `<form>` do html e a classe `.form-group` do **framework boostrap**, pois ficou muito confuso a pergunta, felizmente eu pude identificar porque já utilizei esse framework.

Assim como o Leonardo Marques disse, não tem fechamento da tag html `<form>` nesse código ai, e complemento dizendo que não tem `<button>` ou tag `a` do tipo submit, sendo responsável por disparara  ação de enviar os dados pelo method POST para a pagina processa/proc_cad_pessoa.php